# Duplicate angular component with different property values

Tags: angular, angular4-forms

I have a component which I want to use many times in the same page and also I want to bind different data values when it gets called everytime

This is my component

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
    selector: 'creat-task-validation',
    templateUrl: 'creat-task-validation.component.html'
})

export class CreatTaskValidationComponent implements OnInit {

    @Input() form : FormControl;
    @Input() prop : string;

    constructor() {}
    ngOnInit(){}
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div *ngIf="form.invalid && (form.dirty || form.touched)" class="alert alert-danger padding-5">

    <div *ngIf="form.errors.required">
        {{prop + 'is required .' | translate}}
    </div>
</div>
```

and this how it's called in parent component

```
<creat-task-validation *ngIf="description.invalid && (description.dirty || description.touched)" [prop]="'Description'" [form]="description"></creat-task-validation>
```

Comment: And... what is your question? Note that `[prop]="'Description'"` should simply be `prop="Description"`

Comment: i want to use the same component in another validation in the same form it's get the first value only i want to change it according to the field

Comment: @JB Nizet In case of `prop="Description"` angular reads `@Input` property and also calls `createAttribute` to create attribute while in case of `[prop]` the `prop` attribute won't be created. I don't know exactly how it will affect on performance. I prefer your suggestion but at that time  i have some doubts regarding performance.

Comment: @yurzui you'r totally right the error message only appear at the first field but in the others field nothing happen at all only empty red field without any data

Comment: pass everything changeable to component and make the process there here's example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-egazyj

Comment: @Microsmsm thanx it solve one issue now i can console log the same value i passed but i still got the empty red alert field , only the first field works fine

Comment: did you try to add it as an argument too?

Comment: @Microsmsm could you explain